# How to implement frustum culling in a 2d tile based game? (in a Orthographic View)

Tags: java, opengl, 2d, lwjgl, frustum

I'm making a 2d tiled base game, in which when I render many tiles, the fps goes down drastically. I know why this is happening, its because many objects are being rendered at once. I need to implement frustum culling in the orthographic view, but i don't know how to achieve that.

I've looked through numerous websites, searching all day. But still I can't find how to implement frustum culling in a 2d game.

Note: I'm using VBOs.

Comment: So... what part of frustum culling are you having trouble with?

Comment: How to construct one, I don't know how to actually code the frustum.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between orthographic and perspective views is the clipping volume they represent; For perspective it is a frustum (or a 'square cone') and for orthographic it is a simple box.

You just need a simple AABB-AABB test to cull your sprites, and it's actually pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly sure you don't need a frustum if it is a simple 2D game, can you not in your render method just do an if statement to check if the tiles are still within the bounds of the camera and if not then simply do not render them?

Comment: This _is_ frustum culling, except you normally don't call it like this (see pleluron's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but for those who need it.

How big is your tile? In a simple 2D game it's true that frustrum culling is often unnecessary.

If you're sure culling is the problem, divide your huge tilemap into several smaller tilemaps then draw only those that are within view. The rest is a simple AABB check for each tilemap section.